# Django: Template Form action not redirecting

Tags: html, django

My `Form` action is not redirecting to the passed `view`. I am calling `simple_upload` view method from `login_form.html` form action. Instead, upon clicking the login button, it stays on the same page. Below is my code:

**urls.py:**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from uploads.core import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', views.login_form, name='login_form'),
    url(r'^upload/', views.simple_upload, name='simple_upload'),
    url(r'^drop_down/$', views.drop_down, name='drop_down'),
    url(r'^visualize_view/$', views.visualize_view, name='visualize_view'),
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.AKASH_ROOT)
```

**login_form.html:**

```
{% block content %}

<button onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" style="width:auto;">Login</button>

<div id="id01" class="modal">

  <form class="modal-content animate" action="{% url 'simple_upload' %}" method="get">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="imgcontainer">
      <span class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar2.png" alt="Avatar" class="avatar">
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <label for="uname"><b>Username</b></label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname" required>

      <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
      <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>

      <button type="submit">Login</button>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember"> Remember me
      </label>
    </div>

    <div class="container" style="background-color:#f1f1f1">
      <button type="button" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
      <span class="psw">Forgot <a href="">password?</a></span>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('id01');

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

**views.py:**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
from .models import Document
from .forms import ExpenseForm

def login_form(request):
    return render(request, 'core/login_form.html')


def simple_upload(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello World")
```

**Project hierarchy:**

[image: Project Hierarchy]

Comment: What do you mean by stay on the same page? Does it reload and stay on the same page or it just doesnt do anything?

Comment: It reloads and stays on the same page

Comment: Though, I even see url getting changed to `http://localhost:8000/upload/?csrfmiddlewaretoken=roThWanpNfh8azfEgnyHJNymKcb8xMV1&uname=a&psw=a&remember=on` but the html view comes back to the same.

Comment: Well you are using get, so its adding your params to the URL. I guess your urls.py resolving might have something not right, but I cant figure it out yet.

Comment: At some point of time the code was working. Since I am pretty new to Django and python I unsure of naming conventions, was switching names from underscore to camel case and back to underscore, then I come up with the issue

Comment: What django and python version are you using?

Comment: Django version 1.9.8 and Python 3.7.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your home URL pattern is not terminated, so it matches every path. It should be:

```
url(r'^$', views.login_form, name='login_form'),
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not good form logic. Forms have valid and invalid actions. If your form is valid you redirect to new (success) page your user, but if not you render same (login) page. But firstly you should give a name your login page like below or use Django's inherit auth urls:

```
url(r'^login', views.login_form, name='login_form'),
```

It's my url paths:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views

app_name = "user"

urlpatterns = [
    path('sign_up/', views.sign_up, name="sign_up"),
    path('account_activation_sent/', views.account_activation_sent, name='account_activation_sent'),
    path('activate/<uidb64>/<token>/', views.activate, name="activate"),
    path('login/', views.login_user, name="login"),
    path('logout/', views.logout_user, name="logout"),

    path('password_reset/', views.password_reset, name="password_reset"),
    path('password_reset/done/', views.password_reset_done, name="password_reset_done"),
    path('password_reset/<uidb64>/<token>/', views.password_reset_confirm, name="password_reset_confirm"),
    path('password_reset/complete/', views.password_reset_complete, name="password_reset_complete"),


    path('profile/<slug:slug>/', views.profile, name="profile"),
]
```

I wanna show you my simple login function and you will understand:

```
def login_user(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect("index")
    else:
        form = LoginForm(request.POST or None)
        context = {
            "form": form
        }
        go_to = request.POST.get('next', '/')  
        print(go_to)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get("username")
            password = form.cleaned_data.get("password")
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

            if user is None:
                messages.error(request, "Username or password is incorrect! Try again.")
                return render(request, "auths/login.html", context)

            messages.success(request, "Login successful! Welcome bro.")
            login(request, user)
            go_to = request.POST.get('next', '/')
            if go_to:
                go_to = request.POST.get(
                    'next')
                return redirect(go_to)
            else:
                return redirect("index")
        return render(request, "auths/login.html", context)
```

I use Django's form and It's easy but you can use your custom form in your template. My form is like this:

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(label="Username")
    password = forms.CharField(label="Password", widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(LoginForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['username'].label = ''
        self.fields['password'].label = ''

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'password' )
```

I hope It will help you.

Comment: Thanks for helping in sharing the better ways!